# JSP page compilation "tag cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: jsp, jar, jsp-tags, weblogic-10.x

I am using a custom tags library deployed as a **jar file**. 
When using this lab in a jsp I have following problem:
*_tag cannot be resolved to a type for tags that are NOT used in this specific JSP.

I am using websphere 10.3 as my application server. Any ideas how to solve this issue ?
Mayby I can precompile the tag files and package them in my taglib jar ? How to achieve that ?

example:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="e" uri="http://our.domain.com/tags-e" %> 
<e:div  styleId="xxx" action="prototype" autoload="false"> 
    json content is loaded here 
</e:div>
```

In this example e:div is compiled and there is an error for e:link tag not used on this page. Thanks in advance for any hints.